# Программная эмуляция внешних устройств

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, драйвер

Видел как-то парочку программ, которые эмулируют (вернее "почти эмулируют", потому как через PS/2) - действия с клавиатурой и мышью. Возник вопрос, а можно ли создать нормальные **программные**, не программно-аппаратные эмуляторы для :

- клавиатуры USB
- мыши USB
- микрофона
- камеры

Хотелось бы для клавиатуры и мыши - подавать просто текстовую последовательность действий и задержек, для микрофона - использовать источник *.mp3, *.ogg, *.flac, для камеры - видеопоток x264.

Вопрос конечно же не в "прикладной" кухне описанного, а в системной - можно ли это все сэмулировать программно? И если "да", куда начать копать?

Comment: Можно. Пишите драйвер, который будет предоставлять поддержку соответствующих виртуальных устройств, а также организовывать их создание и уничтожение. Рекомендую изучить примеры, идущие в комплекте с *Windows Driver Kit*; наверняка там есть соответствующий пример.

Comment: Устройства - разнородные. Видать "по одному шаблону" не получиться?

Comment: Ваша задача — реализовать соответствующие программные интерфейсы устройств. А так, понятное дело, что разнородные устройства будут вести себя по разному. Но ничто не мешает обслуживать их одному и тому же драйверу. Ведь драйвер — это все лишь динамическая библиотека, загружаемая вместе с ядром в адресное пространство процесса *System*. Грубо говоря, ядро выполняет  что-то вроде `LoadLibrary` для каждого из драйверов.

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже на то.

Comment: А как по-Вашему работает полная виртуализация?

Comment: В VMWare в списке оборудования я не встречал камеры и микрофона. Возможно USB-камера и подхватиться как-то, возможно и USB-микрофон существует в природе. И, как я понял из ответов, нужно писать дрова для своего USB-устройства, и в нем уже определять функции.